# Managing multiple pages while using footers for navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

In my JQM application I have used a fixed footer for navigating between different modules like Home,Users,Projects etc.This is a trimmed down version of my actual code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function addUser(){
            console.log("sss");
                $.mobile.changePage("#add_user");
            }
            function editUser(){
                $.mobile.changePage("#edit_user");
            }
            function delUser(){
                $.mobile.changePage("#del_user");
            }

        </script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="home">
            <div data-role="content">
                This is Home
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#home" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#users">Users</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="users">
            <div data-role="content">
                This is Users
            </div>
            <input type="button" value="Add a user" onclick="addUser()"/>
            <input type="button" value="Edit user" onclick="editUser()"/>
            <input type="button" value="Delete user" onclick="delUser()"/>
            <div data-role="footer" data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#users" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Users</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div data-role="page" id="add_user">
            <div data-role="content">
               Here users can be added
               <a href="#users" data-role="button">Back to Users</a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#users" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Users</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="page" id="edit_user">
            <div data-role="content">
               Here user details can be edited
            </div>
            <a href="#users" data-role="button">Back to Users</a>
            <div data-role="footer" data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#users" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Users</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="page" id="del_user">
            <div data-role="content">
               Here user can be deleted
            </div>
            <a href="#users" data-role="button">Back to Users</a>
            <div data-role="footer" data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#users" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Users</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

            </body>

            </html>
```

Live demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/n4MZz/

Consider this use case:

1) Click on users tab - Users tab will be loaded with buttons for add/edit/delete

2) Click in Add a user button - Page to add user will be loaded with users tab selected.

3) Click on Home tab.

4) Click on users tab.

Now it will go to the users main page with options to add/edit/delete.I did not want it that way.I want the page with the last action I have performed.In the above use case I want the page to add user to be loaded when i perform Step 4.

Any idea how to achieve this?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `pagebeforeshow` event. See the code + comments below.

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n4MZz/2/**

```
var lastMode = "users";
var lastPageUsers = false;
$("div").live("pagebeforeshow", function(){ //Attach event
    var id = this.id; //Get ID of the requested page
    if(id == "users"){

        //If lastMode is not users and if the last page is not a user page
        if(lastMode != "users" && !lastPageUsers){
            lastPageUsers = true;
            $.mobile.changePage('#'+lastMode);
        }

    } else if(id == "add_user" || id == "edit_user" || id == "del_user"){
        lastMode = id;
    } else { //Not a user page, so set lastPageUsers = false
        lastPageUsers = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I checked the code.It is coming like the users tab is shown first,then it goes to the last mode.Also I am no longer able to go to the main users page via 'Back to Users' button